# Although the textboxes contain values, the variables assigned to them don't, why?

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a windows form where I have several text boxes to introduce the values that will be used several methods.

My intention was to define the variables global, so they can be used throughout the whole programme, but although I get no compilation errors, the variables are empty when I check (there are numbers written in all of them). Here comes some of the variables, maybe I'm assigning wrong the values:

```
//This is in the mainform, where all the textboxes are stored


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1{


public partial class Rotor_Calc:Form

{

        public  Rotor_Calc()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public string T_HotIn
        {
            get { return Temphotin.Text; }
            set { Temphotin.Text = value; }
        }

        public string F_Cold
        {
            get { return flowCold.Text; }
            set { flowCold.Text = value; }
        }

// this is in a class named Globals

public class Globals

{
    public static string THotIn;
    public static string FlowCold;

     public Globals(Rotor_Calc Rotor)

     {
         THotIn = Rotor.T_HotIn;

         FlowCold = Rotor.F_Cold;
}

     public static double Thin = Convert.ToDouble(Globals.THotIn);

     public static double speedCold = Convert.ToDouble(Globals.FlowCold);
}
```

Then, in the following methods I write Globals.Thin, so it can take the value from the textbox, but when I compile it remains empty.

I would like also to take the computed value of another variable and write it in the results textbox. For this purpose I followed the same process backwards:

//In the main form define the textboxes

```
        public string Eff_Hot
        {
            get { return effecthot.Text; }
            set { effecthot.Text = value; }
        }

        public string Eff_Cold
        {
            get { return effectcold.Text; }
            set { effectcold.Text = value; }
        }

//in the globals method, take the value from the calculation method:

public class Globals{


    public static string eff_cold;

    public static string eff_hot;


public Globals(Rotor_Calc Rotor){


         eff_cold = Rotor.Eff_Cold;
         eff_hot = Rotor.Eff_Hot;
}

     public static double effcold=Convert.ToDouble(eff_cold);

     public static double effhot = Convert.ToDouble(eff_hot);
}
```

Of course the last is not working because the calculations inbetween give infinite values.

What am I exactly doing wrong? can somebody help?

Comment: How are you creating the textboxes, have you added them to the controls collection of the form?

Comment: an instance class may be more suitable than a static class for you

Comment: You are not using rotor.showform() or something like this to show the form.

Comment: I created the textboxes in the windows form.

Comment: what do you mean with show the form? the form where all textboxes are?

Would not be very messy if I create instance instead? I just out 2 examples, but the form has like 20 textboxes and 20 radiobuttons and checkboxes, it's kind of big.

I have already this programme working in visual basic, but i really need to translate it.

Comment: Can you show the program.cs main method?

Comment: well... I can write part of it yes. I have several methods, one of them calculated the effectiveness of a HEX:

Comment: class Eff_Calc
{
    public static void effectiveness(...)
    {
        do
        {
           //statements
            if (ch < cc)
            {
//do...
            }
            else if (cc < ch)
            {
//do smthg different
            }
   
            if (cprima > 1)
            {
//do x
            }
            if (cprima < 1)
            {
//do y
            }
                            Tout = Globals.Tcin + (eff * qmax / cc);
            Tout = Globals.Thin - (eff * qmax / ch);
        }
        while (...);
        Globals.Thout = Thoutdef;
        Globals.Tcout = Tcoutdef;

Comment: I rechecked and the main form actually takes the values from the textboxes, but is the Globals class the one that assigns null values to all the variables first.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the fact that this statement:

```
public static double effcold=Convert.ToDouble(eff_cold);
```

is executed as soon as the Globals class is accessed for the first time.

This means that it will always be executed before your constructor `Globals(Rotor_Calc Rotor)` is executed, i.e. it is executed before `eff_cold` and `eff_hot` are assigned a value.

Maybe you should move `effcold=Convert.ToDouble(eff_cold);` and `effhot = Convert.ToDouble(eff_hot);` inside the constructor, but I'm not sure since it's not too clear to me what you are trying to do.

If you are tryng to use Globals to access the value of your TextBoxes from every point of your application, you should keep in Globals a pointer to your Form, not the values. The statements in the constructor are executed just once. This means that you are storing in eff_cold and eff_hot the value of your TextBox at THAT moment, and those values won't be changed unless you execute the constructor again.

Furthermore, I don't like the idea of havin a constructor for a class that contains only static stuff.

A possible working version of your code (if I got it right) could be this one:

```
public class Globals    
{
    public static Rotor_Calc Rotor;

     public static double EffHot
     {
         get { return Convert.ToDouble(Rotor.EffHot); }
         set { Rotor.EffHot = value.ToString(); }
     }

     public static double EffCold
     {
         get { return Convert.ToDouble(Rotor.EffCold); }
         set { Rotor.EffCold = value.ToString(); }
     }
}
```

This should work as long as you set Globals.Rotor = yourInstanceOfRotor_Calc; (maybe with a 
`Globals.Rotor = this;` after the InitializeComponent() of Rotor_Calc).

Anyway, I don't like to keep references to Forms in Globals, I'd prefer some sort of DataBinding.

EDIT according to your last comment:

You can just write a setter for Rotor, assign the values there and call the setter after InitializeComponent():

```
public class Globals    
{
    public static double EffHot;
    public static double EffCold;
    public static Rotor_Calc Rotor
    {
        set 
        {
            EffHot = Convert.ToDouble(Rotor.EffHot);
            EffCold = Convert.ToDouble(Rotor.EffCold);
        }
     }

}
```

Comment: But even at the beginning, I just want to take the values from the text boxes and it is still assigned zero.

The application starts reading the Globals class, instead of the main form, so it assigns a value zero to the actual variables/parameters I will use to calculate, and not the value that reads from the textbox after. 

If I do what you said, then the variables that I want to use for the calculations are no longer inside the Globals class.

Comment: Do you mean that want Globals to reflect the changes made in your TextBoxes? I.e. at the beginning the value is 0, but when you change it to 10 Globals.effcold value is 10.0?

Comment: Not exactly. 

let's see if I can explain myself better. I have a bunch of textboxes where the user has to write the values. Once the value is written and the application running, those never change ( in the code above is Thotin.Text i.e.).

Those should be available already at the beginning, no calculations needed to get the value, just read. 

And then, using these values that are set as variables, I have several methods that calculate i.e. eff_cold. It changes if the values of the first variables change.

Comment: The problem as I see it is that, since it accesses the Globals class before, the values does not change after reading the textboxes.

I think if we figure out how to fix this, the application will work fine ( or other hidden errors will appear!)

Comment: Thanks! I will try now, I'm quite new in this and visual basic is simple in comparison.